# Play framework doesnt start on os x mac

Tags: macos, playframework, java

I'm playing with the play framework, which seems quite fine.
When I tray to start a sample application On Mac 10.6.8  java version 1.6_29 I recive the following error:
Ah! I tryed also whith the openjdk 1.7, but the same error.
Pls. Help I'm trying for 2 day without success. I trayed on a linux machine and everything is fine, but my developpment machine is os x
Thks.
Xaver

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
12:33:13,841 INFO  ~ Starting /Users/xaver/Documents/play-1.2.4/samples-and-tests/yabe
12:33:13,845 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.crud)
12:33:13,859 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/usr/local/Cellar/play/1.2.4/libexec/modules/crud)
12:33:13,859 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.secure)
12:33:13,860 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (/usr/local/Cellar/play/1.2.4/libexec/modules/secure)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getErrors()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.compile(ApplicationClasses.java:277)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:164)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:158)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:294)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
```

Comment: Which java location are you using? It looks like your JAVA_HOME might be pointing to eclipse.

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME says : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem between your dependencies try it

dependencies.yml

```
   - net.sf.jasperreports -> jasperreports 4.6.0:
            exclude :
              - eclipse -> *
```

If it cause you any problem try

```
   - net.sf.jasperreports -> jasperreports 4.6.0:
            transitive: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from eclipse try to rerun the **play eclipsify** command on your project then delete it from eclipse and reimport it.

Comment: Are you sure the jre picked up is the one set in JAVA_HOME? Check your PATH variable or try:   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME\bin:$PATH

Comment: when i type "java -version" in the shell it returns: openjdk version "1.7.0-b222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b222-20111220)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode). I've soft linked java, jar, javah ... in /usr/bin to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/ originally was pointing to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands I assume that must be right. I'm so far to reinstall the system, but I really want to know WHY doesn't work. In any case I followed your last advice, doesnt work anyway

Comment: Ok maybe completely unrelated but the only warning I see are about the modules dependencies and the error seem to be related to loading the modules. Try to define your modules in dependencies.yml and run play deps --sync before play start.

Comment: well, I discovered something new: the play framework seems to use eclipse JTD for code compilation. Recently I've installed eclipse indigo, which after installation did not start, I tried to find the problem, but after some tries I gave up and continued to work with my old eclipse galileo version. I suppose both problems have the same error cause in common. All that happend afer the latest java update and which affect the openjdk too, Then on my mac laptop osx 10.6.8, but without the latest java update everything works as aspected, inclusive the latest eclipse installation (indigo). How now?

Comment: In my case, it was an error within a report, the others worked fine